# Operators in Haskell

Tags: haskell, operators

I wrote the following function

```
foldList :: (Double -> Double -> Double) -> [Double] -> Double
foldList op (x:t)
 | t == []     = x
 | otherwise   = (op) x (foldList op t)
```

and it worked perfectly fine. But when I changed the last line to

```
  | otherwise  = x op (foldList op t)
```

it didn't compile anymore. I am still rather new to Haskell but I thought when dealing with operators

```
a op b
```

is equivalent to

```
(op) a b
```

Do I have to treat `op` as just a normal function? And if so, in what cases is it regarded an operator and why not here?

Comment: Write it as ``a `op` b`` (note the backticks around `op`).

Comment: Operators cannot contain alphanumeric characters, see [the specification.](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operators are functions with symbol names. They’re infix by default, and you can use them like other functions by wrapping them in parentheses.

```
a + b       (+) a b
```

Functions with identifier names, like your `op`, can be used as infix by wrapping them with *backticks*.

```
op a b      a `op` b
```

See also https://wiki.haskell.org/Infix_operator